# HTTP get returns content-type html/text instead of application/json

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to make a React app for a project that pulls data from an existing API, and I got stuck on something that I have no idea why it's happening. I'll try to explain it:

I have three different files which are supposed to be working together: two components (one called [SearchOffers](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EDiN9ZbMD4pbiEHb7xNGR2mA-OR4xKEz) and the other called [OfferResults](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VbUh0IuM4jf1YD23m4-21HCI3vM1UOVJ)) and a file ([get-data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/107ExLSK4GhFgfxiGPIOKg6n9c5W2KAsZ/view?usp=sharing)) to keep the request functions.

Inside `get-data` there is a function called `getJSON` that given an URL and its parameters returns the JSON provided by that request. I've made an example right after the function to prove that it works just fine.

The issue here is that whenever I try to fill the forms on `SearchOffers` and hit send, the console outputs `Invalid content-type.
Expected application/json but received text/html; charset=UTF-8`. Even though it's a known error, I don't understand why when I execute the function separately I get a normal JSON from the request but here I get a text/html.

I know the code is quite big, but neither me nor my teacher have no clue why this is happening. If anyone could please help me out, I'd appreciate it a lot!

Comment: Can you embed the relevant code snippets here instead of on google drive?

Comment: I don't know how much of the code I should embed here. The codes are quite large and I believe that all of it is important to understand the logic I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: I would then suggest to take the relevant parts, and keep simplifying and removing things until you get to the minimum code snippet that can reproduce the issue.